# Are netcat connections stored to any log file in Linux?

Tags: linux, logs, netcat

I have opened a service:

```
nc -l -p 1234 -e service.sh
```

If someone connects to this service.

```
nc xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1234
```

Can this connection be found in any Linux log file?

Comment: if some answer helps you, kindly [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the check mark. That'll contribute some reputation to both of you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, network connections are not logged by Linux by default. You can view *current* connections with a variety of tools, e.g. `sudo lsof -P -n -i`, but the system does not keep a history of network connections--that's up to the application. Web servers, ssh, mail servers, etc. all do this in their own ways, but `nc` is designed more for testing than production and does not have logging. If you want to log `nc` connections, you could use `iptables` or network sniffing tools or add logging to `service.sh`.

As an additional assurance that the connection is not being logged by the system, use a unique port number, e.g. `nc -l -p 58404 -e service.sh`, make a connection to this from another computer, and then search through **all** of your system logs for that port number:

```
sudo find /var/log -type f -exec zcat -f {} + |grep 58404
sudo journalctl |grep 58404
```